# jenkins selenium grid plugin failing to start configuration on nodes but starts on master

Tags: selenium, jenkins

I installed the Jenkins Selenium Grid plugin. 
I added a new configuration and set it to work for "all nodes", and set the browser to be  Firefox 21.0.
When I go to the config url for master, computer/(master)/selenium/ I am able to see it working.
[image]

When I go to the config url for any of the slaves that it should be working with, and I press the "Start" button, nothing seems to happen.
[image]

Any Help is appreciated.

Comment: You may need to install or configure selenium on the relevant slaves.

Comment: The point of the Jenkins Selenium Grid plugin is that it should do that work for you...

Comment: Usually it is your responsibility to install any required tools, and in the plugin you just specify where Jenkins can find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue turned out to be that the Master machine was in an EC2 cloud, while the slave machines were were in our internal work network. So basically a firewall configuration issue. It sure would have been nice if the Selenium Grid Plugin for jenkins was would at a minimum display some sort of an error in a place that's obvious to the user. Right now the error was output in the Jenkins log.

Answer (score 1):

Should make sure Selenium is up and running on the different slaves as well.

See here for a great tutorial by *[Torben Hansen](https://plus.google.com/101758584571390672795)* on using Selenium with Jenkins:
**[Setting up Jenkins CI, Selenium grid and PHPUnit Selenium to perform integration testing](http://www.derhansen.de/2013/03/setting-up-jenkins-ci-selenium-grid-and.html)**

Answer (score 0):

Check if selenium-server-standalone-X.XX.X.jar is in the Jenkins_Home folder for each jenkins slave.
If there is no such jar, just paste it to a Jenkins_Home folder for all of the slaves and reboot the master node.

The up and running configuration will automatically appear at "Selenium node Management" for each slave.